# How to measure object size roughly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

### Background

I am working on exporting a SQL database with about 50 different tables into a set of JSON files which I can publish on GitHub to make it easy for others to bootstrap their projects with data. All they would need to do is read the JSON files, modify however they like, and insert into their own database.

The problem is, you can't have very large strings as JSON files, because Node.js has a limit either on `JSON.parse` argument size, or string size (I forget). So in my mind, divide the content into a set of JSON files, and then have an explanation that you need to `glob` match the files in a folder to get the JSON, like `./data/**/*.json` sort of thing.

I thought about just publishing a SQL database, but I hate it when open data projects do that. The reality is, their SQL format will not match yours, so you *need* to serialize it to JSON or something like that ultimately, from their SQL database, to convert it into your SQL/NoSQL/GraphDB sort of format, and that is just a painful experience. And the db dump is often a binary format so it's not human readable at all. Sometimes you just want to peek at the data to get a sense of it, and having JSON is nice for that. Any binary file is a no-go in terms of using git in my book. It explodes the git history every time you commit a new binary file with 1 "value" changed, etc..

I thought about CSV, but it's heavily tree-structured data which is being exported.

One of the comments suggested JSON line-delimited streams, which is a good idea, but dealing with JSON streams is a lot more complicated than glob-loading a bunch of files IMO, and the `.json` file isn't actually parseable as JSON, which is often a source of confusion. So probably will avoid that.

In my case, I will only need to watch out for JSON file size on **lists** of data, not on individual records.

*The data is "simple" tree data in that there are no circular dependencies.*

### Question

What are some heuristic ways of measuring the size of a JavaScript object? May main goal is to limit the size of the resulting JSON file size so its string is smaller than [256 MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957890/javascript-string-size-limit-256-mb-for-me-is-it-the-same-for-all-browsers) it seems. I mean I could do `Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(obj), 'utf8')` every time I add a new property or item to an array, but that would constantly serialize a string which is growing every step, which would be slow.

What other approaches would make this a somewhat clean way of measuring JSON string size while constructing an in-memory object? Perhaps just do something like this to add properties to your object?

```
let totalSize = 0;

function addProperty(obj, name, value) {
  totalSize += 2 + name.length; // 2 for qoutes on each side
  // this is just for string,
  // would have to test on all types.
  totalSize += 2 + value.length;

  obj[name] = value
}
```

Wondering if there is a library for this already, or a set of established patterns for solving this, or if what I sort of started there makes sense. Open to any ideas on this.

*It doesn't have to be perfect, just even estimating at a high end the size would be fine.*

I guess just doing a relatively-quick `JSON.stringify(listItem, null, 2)` on each item, and adding that to the running total, will mean we aren't stringifying more than twice, which I think will be fast enough. If I really wanted I could progressively build up the JSON string even, one list item at a time, hmm maybe that would work. But that is an over-optimization at this point, probably stringifying twice would be fine.

What are other beneficial ways of doing this? Of calculating JSON object size so it doesn't go over the max. I would probably limit each file to like 8mb to be honest.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77450348/edit) the question to include a [mre] which produces the error? (Questions obviously can't include hundreds of MB of data, but a function which generates such a JSON string for parsing should suffice for the reproduction.)

Comment: If your concern is to have a single string that's less than 256MB, you have _very_ different problems to solve. Like "maybe it's time to use task-appropriate data structures, operational transforms, and maybe a database" instead of working with huge JSON files. What are you actually _doing_ that makes you ask this question? Because this is almost certainly [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Estimating how large JSON will be is possible.  You just have to code for all the types, and you have to handle object embedded into other objects in a recursive manner and, if this needs to be bulletproof, then you need to protect against circular references.  I also agree with the other comments that suggest that perhaps JSON is not the ideal format for whatever it is that you're trying to do here.

Comment: In these cases it may be a sign that the format you are using is ill-fitted to your purpose. Rather than hacking JSON into something it is not made to do, would something like [JSONL](https://jsonlines.org/) serve you better? You can read it and parse it record by record.

Comment: Or, depending on the data, maybe just a serially written .CSV file.  You can have as many lines of data as you want without ever holding more than one at a time in memory as you construct each line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How much memory do javascript objects take in Node.js vs Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77312855/438273)

Comment: @jsejcksn OP was asking about JSON size, not object size.

Comment: Two alternate approaches are [new line delimited json](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec) (if the data structure permits) and streaming JSON parsers.

Comment: I would like for it to be open source data which is easy to work with, so that means no SQL database and no streaming JSON, it must be simple JSON. But this does mean I would have to divide it into files, which makes extra work... So perhaps streaming JSON is a solution.... It's just a little less intuitive.

Comment: @jfriend00 unfortunately its tree data, so CSV wouldn't be that straightforward. But good suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this is a database dump which is somewhat human readable and published to GitHub. So JSON makes the most sense I think. I _hate it_ when "open data" projects publish a SQL database, kill me.

Comment: Well, kind of hard for us to help solve the REAL problem here when we have no idea what the data looks like.

Comment: Can't say JSON makes _any_ sense to me in that case. Just use a sqlite file if it's a database snapshot, and pull data from that as needed without transferring huge JSON files. Also, don't read SQL: import it into a database. That's the whole point of SQL files. They're not meant to be read, they're meant to be imported, which is a trivial operation n pretty much every popular database engine.

Comment: @Lance I don't see why you equate "open" to "human-readable". But if it's a dump from a relational database, I see no reason why a streaming format of tuples wouldn't work.